# How do I disable desktop icons?

Tags: gnome, 10.10, desktop-icons

I don't like icons on my desktop. On Windows I simply click right on the desktop and uncheck *"Show Desktop Icons"* or so. Couldn't find any similar option in Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Sry it seems that I overlooked it somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To disable the desktop icons, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gconf-editor` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After the Configuration Editor opens, expand the "apps" tree and scroll down and expand the "nautilus" menu, click on "preferences" and uncheck "show_desktop".

[image: gconf-editor]